# Performance issue with ORDER BY + AND in sqlite

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I'm experiencing some weird behavior with SELECT statements in sqlite. There is one table with 3 Million records. E.g.

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cond1;
```

reduces the output to 10000 records and finishes instantly. Same with

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cond1 ORDER BY col1;
```

But

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cond1 AND cond2 ORDER BY col1;
```

seems to take forever. The CPU is working for about 2 seconds and after that there is only I/O. CPU does nothing, memory is free.

What am I doing wrong?

Hope, it's not a newbie question and all i have to do is using an index (but why?).
Thx for help!

More concrete:
the table structure:

```
    0|url|TEXT|0||1
    1|date|DATE|0||1
    2|md5sum|TEXT|0||0
    3|size|INTEGER|0||0
    4|archive|TEXT|0||0
    5|numScripts|INTEGER|0||0
    6|numScriptBytes|INTEGER|0||0
    7|numLinesBehaviour|INTEGER|0||0
    8|state|TEXT|0||0
```

the statement:

```
    SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE md5sum LIKE "00%" AND state=="okay" ORDER BY md5sum;
```

There is no connection between md5sum and state.

I haven't created any indexes.

What i also forgot to mention: The problem occurs only when the statement includes two or more string comparisons AND ordering. So

```
    SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE md5sum LIKE "00%" AND state=="okay";
```

works also fine.

2 Update:
An obvious workaround:

```
    CREATE TABLE temp (url TEXT, date DATE, ...
    INSERT INTO temp SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE state=="okay" AND md5sum LIKE "00%";
    SELECT * FROM temp ORDER BY md5sum;
```

But, damn, there must be an easier way.

Comment: It depends on what is written in condition cond2; are columns involved in cond2 indexed? If you provide your table def we can try help you better...

Comment: You're asking ask to guess what's in `cond1` and `cond2`.  Something about those conditions (probably combined with the indexes you've created on the table) is turning the query from one that's optimizable to one that isn't.  Please post the table structure and the actual SELECT statements you're sending to the database.

Comment: ok, more concrete: there are no logical connections between cond1 and cond2. So the sets are overlapping. Also there are no indexes yet at all.

Comment: `state` column could be converted to int and indexed; anyway your `LIKE` part makes query scans all records, so I don't know if you can make it faster...

Comment: yeah i know. But the point is it happens only if there are two or more string comparisons. I would expect sqlite to first select the matching records and after that to order the results. But somehow the conditions are connected to the ordering so that the whole table is sorted

Comment: Could you please give us a header for the table so that we know the column names?

Comment: And wait a minute...`state=="okay"`?  In SQL, `=` is used for equality comparison.

Comment: could you try a subquery ? Since SQLite is file based if I'm right, crossing conditions line by line might be the source of inefficiency.

Comment: in sqlite there is no difference between = and ==.

Comment: and i cant find a subquery that finishes in constant time with the same result as     SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE md5sum LIKE "00%" AND state=="okay";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I haven't created any indexes.

That implies that the DBMS will have to inspect *every row* of your table just to make the selection.

> ORDER BY md5sum;

That implies that the DBMS has to sort (typically an  N log(N) operation) the result set.

Adding indexes may help, either by making the checking of your condition cheaper, or by making the sorting unneeded. (and maybe both)

UPDATE (added):

Since md5sum is part of both the selection condition and the orderby  expression, you might try to fool the queryplan generator by adding a bogus term to the sorting expression:

```
SELECT * from table1
WHERE md5sum LIKE '00%' AND status = 'Ok'
ORDER BY md5sum, status
;
```

No guarantees, YMMV.

Comment: but wait: selecting can not be the problem when its works without ordering. Ordering is also fast (10000 rows in n*log(N) shouldn't be a problem). But BOTH at the same time freezes the system? There must be some explanation for this.

Comment: Well, in your case the conditions for the selections and the expression for the ordering are orthogonal: you can't have both. Oops, now I see that you have the ugly like md5sum in your selection. Putting md5sum into some kind of index would be the first step.

Comment: ok, thanks. I will do that. But I still cant believe that the MS isn't able to figure out that its much faster to do the ordering after the selection.

Comment: hmm, no. No difference. But I created an index on md5sum and now its working.

Comment: Also: the LIKE operator is _expected_ to be expensive. If you *can* replace it by a "where md5sum >= '00' AND md5sum < '01'", you should certainly consider that option.